# Prolog infinite loop issue

Tags: prolog, failure-slice

I have the below functions.
When I call it with `final_filter([(2, 2)], R)`, it prints a lot of "2 2" pairs. When I comment `get_all_sums(S, _)` it works fine, however if I test separately `get_all_sums(4, R)`. I works also fine, what could be the problem?

```
get_all_sums_R(NR, IT, []):- IT > NR - 2.
get_all_sums_R(NR, IT, R):-
    A is IT,
    B is NR-IT,
    A >= B,
    NEXT_IT is IT + 1,
    get_all_sums_R(NR, NEXT_IT, R_NEXT),
    append([(A, B)], R_NEXT, R).
get_all_sums_R(NR, IT, R):-
    A is IT,
    B is NR-IT,
    A < B,
    NEXT_IT is IT + 1,
    get_all_sums_R(NR, NEXT_IT, R).

get_all_sums(NR, R):-get_all_sums_R(NR, 2, R).


get_all_divisors(X, IT, []):-IT > X/2.
get_all_divisors(X, IT, R):-
    IT =< X/2,
    TMP_RES is mod(X, IT),
    TMP_RES =:= 0,
    NEXT_IT is IT + 1,
    get_all_divisors(X, NEXT_IT, R_NEXT),
    append([IT], R_NEXT, R).
get_all_divisors(X, IT, R):-
    IT =< X/2,
    NEXT_IT is IT + 1,
    get_all_divisors(X, NEXT_IT, R).

get_all_products_R([], _, []).
get_all_products_R([H|L], NR, R):-
    A is H,
    B is NR/H,
    A >= B,
    get_all_products_R(L, NR, NEXT_R),
    append([(A, B)], NEXT_R, R).
get_all_products_R([H|L], NR, R):-
    A is H,
    B is NR/H,
    A < B,
    get_all_products_R(L, NR, R).

get_all_products(NR, R):-
    get_all_divisors(NR, 2, R_LEFT),
    get_all_products_R(R_LEFT, NR, R).

single_element([_]).

final_filter([(A, B)|_], _):-
    write(A),
    P is A*B,
    S is A+B,
    get_all_products(P, PRODUCTS),
    get_all_sums(S, _),
    write(A),write(' '), write(B), write('\n'),
    not(single_element(PRODUCTS)).
```

Comment: What do you expect? `get_all_sums(S, _).` produces an instantiation error and `get_all_sums(4, R), false` does not terminate

Comment: I tried it % d:/newl compiled 0,00 sec, 14 clauses
1 ?- get_all_sums(4, R).
R = [ (2, 2)] .

2 ?- get_all_sums(4, _).
true .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The central misunderstanding here is what termination means in Prolog. That is, **universal termination**. The query of interest is the following:

```
?- get_all_sums(4,R).
   R = [(2,2)]█
```

Prolog's top-level shell offers you first a single answer. But you get more of them by entering <kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>SPACE</kbd>. So Prolog was not finished when showing you the first answer/solution. In fact:

```
?- get_all_sums(4,R).
   R = [(2,2)]
;  R = [(2,2),(3,1)]
;  R = [(2,2),(3,1),(4,0)]
;  R = [(2,2),(3,1),(4,0),(5,-1)]
;  R = [(2,2),(3,1),(4,0),(5,-1),(6,-2)]
;  R = [(2,2),(3,1),(4,0),(5,-1),(6,-2),(7,-3)]
;  R = [(2,2),(3,1),(4,0),(5,-1),(6,-2),(7,-3),(8,-4)]
;  R = [(2,2),(3,1),(4,0),(5,-1),(6,-2),(7,-3),(8,-4),(9,-5)]
; ... .
```

Do you really want to enumerate all negative sums? Looks infinite to me!

But let's concentrate on the non-termination property alone...

Maybe the system will stop after 8 solutions? Is there a better way to be
sure?  Simply "turn off" the display of solutions as follows:

```
?- get_all_sums(4,R), false.
```

Now we are no longer irritated by solutions/answers, and we can concentrate on the termination property alone.  I will further add such goals
`false` and more into your program, to localize the actual reason for non-termination.  The resulting program is called a failure-slice.  And no matter how I add `false` goals, it always holds that: If the failure-slice does not terminate, then the original program does not terminate either.  After a bit of trying, I get:

```
get_all_sums_R(NR, IT, []):- false, IT > NR - 2.
get_all_sums_R(NR, IT, R):- NR = 4,
    A is IT,
    B is NR-IT,
    A >= B,
    NEXT_IT is IT + 1,
    get_all_sums_R(NR, NEXT_IT, R_NEXT), false,
    append([(A, B)], R_NEXT, R).
get_all_sums_R(NR, IT, R):- false,
    A is IT,
    B is NR-IT,
    A < B,
    NEXT_IT is IT + 1,
    get_all_sums_R(NR, NEXT_IT, R).

get_all_sums(NR, R):-get_all_sums_R(NR, 2, R), false.

?- get_all_sums(4, R), false.
```

So this little remaining part is responsible for non-termination. In order to fix this, you will have to add some goals here.  To be sure: `NR = 4`, `A` increases by 1, `B` decreases by one.  And as long as `A >= B`, this loop will continue.

You might be tempted to add somewhere a cut, or a `once/1`. But this
will lead you only from one bug to the other.  Better address the problem above.